# Why is my project identifying way more files and folders than there actually are?

Tags: html, windows, windows-10

I am working on an HTML website. If I go into my project, highlight everything, and check the properties I see the following:

- Size: 16.2 MB
- Size on disk: 16.4 MB
- 120 files
- 19 folders

If I right click the folder containing all of these files I get the following:

- Size: 120 MB
- Size on disk: 121 MB
- 576 files
- 246 folders

If I download my project from GitHub, I see the smaller (and actual) size of my project. I've tried refreshing the folder and my desktop, as well as restarting my computer. Is this an issue and should I be worried?

Comment: What tool are you using?  Visual Studio creates a very large database file for even small projects.

Comment: @DaveS It's just an HTML website. I'm simply opening the containing folder as a Brackets project.

Comment: It seems that you're using Git, so probably your file explorer is taking the `.git` folder into account.